# Which option is grammatically correct

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an essay for school; and as a non-native English speaker I'd like to know which sentence is grammatically correct or which feels "more right", so to speak.

> "a plausible reason for why the firm finds itself in this situation is
>   not being able to adapt to the recent changes in consumer behavior"

or

> "a plausible reason for why the firm finds itself in this situation is
>   for not being able to adapt to the recent changes in consumer
>   behavior"

I'm personally inclined to choose the first one, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You mean "a plausible reason why the company finds itself unable to adapt to the recent changes in consumer behavior"? I removed 'for' out of 'reason for why', 'is/is for' ('finds' is already taking a verb place) and changed 'not being able to' to 'unable to'.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of both *for*s and phrase the second half differently:

> A plausible reason why the firm finds itself in this situation is its inability to adapt to the recent changes in consumer behavior.

I think *inability* is a better and simpler noun than *not being able*. In any case, the second *for* is not grammatical.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't say _inability_ because I used this term later on and I didn't want to repeat myself, but looking back on it now, it doesn't seem like using this term twice will affect the essay in any negative way.